# How to start tmux upon running terminal?

Tags: shell, terminal, tmux, terminal-emulator

I'm using xfce, and want to create a shortcut `Super + t` for starting up terminal with tmux. What command should I put it to execute upon shortcut? I tried `st tmux attach` , however it fails when there isn't any tmux session running(instead, the terminal appears for a fraction of a second and doesn't even let me see what the problem is).

Normal `st tmux` causes, which is .

For some time, I used the following in my .bashrc:

```
# get into tmux at start
[ -z "$TMUX" ] && { tmux attach || exec tmux new-session; }
```

But I removed it, as it was inconvienent when I wanted to run the terminal without tmux. And to add to that, I couldn't use bash at all when my partition was full. Couldn't even login!

Answer (score 1):

How I worked around it:

I created a script `start-tmux.sh`, which contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
# if not inside tmux, then start it.

if [ -z "$TMUX" ]; then
    tmux attach || exec tmux new-session
else
    echo "already in tmux!"
fi
```

And I execute command `st start-tmux.sh` upon hitting `Super + t`